# Fail to login into system with Whitelabel Error Page error

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

**This is my configure method**

Configuration for role based login.

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/signin")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/index")
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();

        /*
         * http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests() .antMatchers("/signin",
         * "/resources/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/img/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
         * .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/signin").permitAll().and().
         * logout() .invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
         * .logoutRequestMatcher(new
         * AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
         */
    }
```

**controller class**

```java
    @RequestMapping("/signin")
    public String customLogin(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Login Page");
        return "login";
    }
```

**html page**

```html
    <section class="bg-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
                    <div class="my-card text-center">
                        <h2><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></h2>
                        
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="my-details border">
                    
                        <form id="login-form" class="form" th:action="@{/signin}" action="#" method="post">
                        <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">
                                Invalid username and password
                            </div>
                            
                             <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
                                You have been logged out
                            </div>
                            
                             <div th:if="${param.change}" class="alert alert-success">
                                <p th:text="${param.change}"></p>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label><br>
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label><br>
                                <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"
                                value="remember-me"> Remember me <span
                                class="text-right" style="padding-left: 140px"> <a
                                    th:href="@{/signup}"> Register here</a></span>
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
                                <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**controller for landing page after login**

This is the controller of login landing page.

```java
    @RequestMapping("/user/index")
    public String dashboard(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "User Dashboard");
        return "dashboard";
    }
```

login with credentials from database and after that I got 403 error but the url `/user/index` present in controller class and the dashboard HTML page is also present.

Comment: Does you user have the role `USER`?

Comment: in data base role is USER_ROLE

Comment: Then the role has the wrong name. It has to be `ROLE_USER`.